# Passando resultado do compare -metric para variável - Imagem de IMAGEMAGICK

Tags: bash, shell-script, imagemagick

Estou comparando duas imagens usando o ImageMagick no Terminal LINUX.

Quando digito na linha do Terminal isso (abaixo) ele me retorna um valor:

```
$ compare -metric mae 0.jpg 2.jpg null:
```

Porém näo consigo colocar esse valor numa variável para posteriormente fazer uma comparaçäo dentro de um Script BASH. Abaixo como escrevo e me dá erro (ou melhor: A variável continua vazia e o valor ainda sai na tela):

```
var=`compare -metric mae 0.jpg 2.jpg null:`
```

nem assim funciona:

```
var=$(compare -metric mae 0.jpg 2.jpg null:)
```

Quando digito: `echo $var` näo sai nada! Alguém me ajuda?

Como passo para uma variável o valor de um `COMPARE -METRIC`?

Comment: Tente `var=$(compare -metric mae 0.jpg 2.jpg null: 2>&1)`

Comment: Valeu Valdeci!!! Era isso mesmo! Faltava o 2>&1 .... Agora funciona perfeitamente!!!!